# What are the subsets of the unit circle that can be the points in which a power series is convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, circles

Let $A\subset\Bbb C$ be a subset of the unit circle. Consider the following condition on $A$.

> **Cond.** There exists a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of complex numbers such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$$ is a power series with radius of convergence $1,$ and $A$ is exactly the subset of the unit circle in which the series converges.

Are there any interesting conditions on a subset $A$ of the unit circle which imply, are implied by or are equivalent to **Cond.**? I think all finite subsets of the circle have this property. What about the countable subsets? Does it have anything to do with measurability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [POST](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6526953) or, indeed, the whole thread.  A quote:

> The convergence set has to be F_sigma_delta, since
>   the (pointwise) convergence set for any sequence
>   of continuous functions is F_sigma_delta.
>
> Herzog and Piranian (together) proved in 1949 that
>   any F_sigma subset of |z| = 1 can be the convergence set
>   of some power series with radius of convergence 1. Lukasenko
>   proved in 1978 that some G_delta subsets of |z| = 1 cannot
>   be the convergence set of any power series with radius of
>   convergence 1. For a fairly elementary survey of the problem
>   of characterizing the convergence set for a power series
>   in C (complex numbers), see Thomas W. Korner, "The
>   behavior of power series on their circle of convergence"
>   [pp. 56-94 in "Banach Spaces, Harmonic Analysis, and
>   Probability Theory", Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics
>   995, Springer-Verlag, 1983]. This is a beautifully written
>   paper that contains detailed proofs of virtually everything
>   and is pitched at the level of a beginning graduate student
>   in math.
>
> Dave L. Renfro