# Convergence power series in boundary

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Say I have a power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ with radius of convergence $0<R<\infty$. What can be said topologically about the set $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid |z|=R\,\mbox{ and }\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \mbox{ converges}\}$ ? Is it possible for there to be an isolated point? Is it possible that it converges for only one point in the boundary of the circle? Thanks!

Comment: One more MSE question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206299/what-are-the-subsets-of-the-unit-circle-that-can-be-the-points-in-which-a-power

Answer (score 7):

I believe that this problem has not been solved completely.

In 1922, Mazurkiewicz showed that every closed and every open set on the boundary is a set of convergence. This settles your particular question. (I'll think a bit about a concrete example, and edit it in if and when I find one.)

In 1948, Herzog and Piranian strengthened this to show that every $F_\sigma$ set is a set of convergence. On the other hand, Lukasenko (1978) gave an example of a $G_\delta$ set which is *not* a set of convergnce.

(It's not too hard to show that every convergence set has to be a $F_{\sigma\delta}$ set, this is even true for the set of points where any sequence of continuous functions converge pointwise.)

**References**

- Mazurkiewicz, S., *Sur les séries de puissances*, Fund. Math, **3** (1922), 52-58
- Herzog, F., Piranian, G., *Sets of convergece of Taylor series. I.*, Duke Math J., **16** (1949), 529-534.
- Lukašenko, S. Ju., *Sets of divergence and nonsummability for trigonometric series*,  Vestnik Moskov. Univ. Ser. I Mat. Mekh. 1978, no. 2, 65–70.

---

**Further reading**

It turns out that this question was posed on [Math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49395/) with a very long and thorough reply. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82871).

Comment: Thanks! I learned something today.

Comment: [This MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49395/) contains further explanations and references.

Comment: @Martin Thank you! That's a much better and more complete answer than mine!

Comment: Andres attributes Lukašenko's result to Körner. I left a comment pointing this out.

Comment: @Martin This question is relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82871 I believe Körner is mostly a survey paper (I don't have access to it right now).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Körner's essay is a survey, nicely written with very detailed proofs, but there are no references at all, only an occasional attribution of very classical results to Lusin, Kolmogorov, Hahn, etc. [Here's a link to the online version](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0061888) (restricted access, though). The first two pages in the preview give a good impression of how the text continues. I think it would be a good idea to link to these two answers by Andres in the body of your answer to make them more prominently visible.

Comment: @Martin I learned about Lukašenko's paper in an old sci.math post by Dave Renfro. A little googling turned up this one: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6526953

Comment: Thanks for the Lukašenko reference!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a power series can converge on isolated points of its "circle" of convergence.

Lusin has constructed a power series $f(z)$ with the radius of convergence of 1 but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Big|\sum^n_{k=0}a_k z^k\Big|=\infty$ for every $z\in\mathbb{S}^1$.
Later, Sierpiński modified Lusin's example to create a power series
which converges at $z = 1$ but diverges on all other points of the unit circle.

For positive integer $m$, let $g_m(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} z^k = \frac{1-z^m}{1-z}$ and $h_m(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} z^{mk} g_m(e^\frac{-2\pi i k}{m} z)$. $g_m(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $m-1$ and $h_m(z)$ is one with degree $m^2-1$. Lusin's $f(z)$ is defined by:
$$
   f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m^{-1/2} z^\frac{2m^3 - 3m^2+m}{6} h_m(z)
$$
and Sierpiński's modification is given by:
$$
   g(z) = (1-z)f(z^2) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (-1)^r a_{[\frac{r}{2}]} z^r
$$

I have copied these examples from the book:

```
North-Holland Mathematics Studies (Vol 208)  
Nine introductions in Complex Analysis  
Sanford L. Segal
```

Please consult its *Charter 6, Natural boundaries* for more details.