# what are the borders of the convergence disks of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Let $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\}$. For which $S\subseteq \mathbb{T}$, is there a sequence $(a_n)\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ such that the series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{a_kz^k}$$
is convergent on $S$ and is not convergent on $\mathbb{T}\setminus S$?

Comment: This is a difficult problem, and according to math overflow the answer is not known (the answer here has a lot of information, though: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49395/behaviour-of-power-series-on-their-circle-of-convergence)

Comment: .... good thread! thanks.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82871 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288765 and