# Complex power series on the circle of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to find examples of complex power series $\sum a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence $1$ and where:

(1) The series converges everywhere on the circle $|z| = 1$ except one point; 
(2) The series diverges everywhere on the circle $|z| = 1$ except one point.

For (1) I found $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ which is a harmonic series when $|z| = 1$. It converges for $|z|=1, z \neq 1$ by Dirichlet test: $\sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\theta}$ bounded and $1/n$ decreasing

**Can anyone give an example for part (2)?**

Comment: In part (2), should it read $|z| = 1$, since you wrote earlier that the series is converging for $|z|<1$?

Comment: According to *An Introduction to Classical Complex Analysis, Vol 1* by  R.RB. Burkel, page 81, an example of 2) due to Sierpinksi (who else?)  can be found in a 1929 paper by Landau.  Unfortunately, I found this on Google books, and it doesn't display the appropriate page of the bibliography, so I can't narrow it down for you any more, but perhaps this will get you started.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=460987  The French translation referred to can be found at http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Sierpinski%20Oeuvres%20Choisies%20I.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288765/convergence-power-series-in-boundary

Comment: @saulspatz Cute! You found a message that I posted at `sci.math` 15 years ago.

Comment: @saulspatz.  Thank you.  I see now its not a trivial follow-up to the first part.