# Lacunary function doesn't converge anywhere on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Consider the Lacunary function 
$$f(z)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2^{n}}=z+z^{2}+z^{4}+z^{8}+\cdots $$

which is analytic over the interior of the open unit disk. It is easy to show that $f(z)$ doesn't have limits at $2^n$-th roots of unity (see wikipedia), which form a dense subset of unit circle. [Wikipedia claims that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function)

> hence by continuous extension every point on the unit circle must be a singularity of $f$.

Why does this hold? Suppose $f$ has a limit at one point of the unit circle, does it necessarily have limits everywhere in some neighborhood of it, and thus contradicts to the fact that the there is a dense subset of unit circle where $f$ doesn't have limits? (generally this is not sure, see Riemann Function)

I don't see how the linked post solve my question. I am asking about a very specific power series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence power series in boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288765/convergence-power-series-in-boundary)

Comment: Protip: If you are going to suggest someone to check wikipedia or any online resourse, provide the link in your post. square brackets for title and parenthesis for url.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are saying that the unit circle is a [natural boundary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html) for the function.  If $f$ were analytic at any point on the unit circle, it would be analytic in a small disk about that point, but the disk would necessarily contain an $n$th root of unity, contradiction.

Comment: Okay... but do limits exist there at all? I know analytic continuation will fail.

Comment: Even if the disk is a natural boundary for $f$, in general $f(\zeta)$ can exist for a given $\zeta$ on the unit disk without being analytic there. They are saying a little more: in the example analyzed, the series representing $f$ *diverges at every point of the unit circle*.

Comment: That I'm not sure about.  Note that singularity is a point at which $f$ is not analytic.  It's quite possible for a power series to converge at a boundary point, but the function not to have an analytic function at that point.  See [Pringsheim's Theorem](https://sunlimingbit.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/pringsheim-theorem/)  In the special case in your question, I don't know.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri How does one see this?

Comment: There is an example of Wacław Sierpiński, published in 1916 on the "Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo", titled "*Sur une série potentielle qui, étant convergente en tout point de son cercle de convergence, représente sur ce cercle une fonction discontinue*" where he constructs a series whose natural boundary is the unit circle, but converges at each of its point to a *discontinuous* function.

Comment: At present I do not remember a precise example involving only one point of non analyticity. However, again Sierpinski produced an example of a power series converging at one point of the unit circle by modifying an earlier example by Lusin.

Comment: The notes to chapter III of the book "*An Introduction to Classical Complex Analysis*" Burckel provide nice insight on the wild behavior of holomorphic function on the natural boundary of their domain of definition.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thanks, but what I meant was, how does one see in the present example that the series diverges at every point on the unit circle?

Comment: Some interesting remarks on Sierpinski's paper are given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110345/does-a-power-series-converging-everywhere-on-its-circle-of-convergence-define-a)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86683/discussion-between-daniele-tampieri-and-saulspatz).

Comment: Have you got a clear answer @Alp?