# How can a power series diverge?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

As we all know, a power series converges within its radius of convergence. Usually the problem is to understand what happens on the boundary.

We can converge on all of the boundary, as for example $\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{z^k}{1+k^2}$ does. Or we can diverge on all of the boundary, as for example $\sum_{k\geq 0} k^2 z^k$ does.

My question is now:

> If we pick a set $A\subseteq S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Can we always find a power series $\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k z^k$ with radius of convergence equal $1$ such that $\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k x^k$ converges for $x\in A$ and diverges for $x\in S\setminus A$?

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288765/42969 (with links to more similar threads).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing out my failure to try the most basic strategy to get an answer. Should have checked more carefully.