# What are the practical applications of $\aleph_2$? Does there exist a set with such cardinality that is ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The power set of $\mathbb{R}$ is often described as being "bigger" or $\aleph _2,$ more infinite than the already infinite number line.

I'm wondering a few general things about this:

One, what practical spaces of objects have a cardinality of $\aleph_2$?

Are there any relevant theorems about mappings to and from sets that have a cardinality of $\aleph_2$?

Further, does there exist a set with a cardinality of $\aleph_2$ that can be ordered, or is ordering intrinsically impossible on a set with such cardinality?

In other words, why study larger infinities like $\aleph_2,$ what are these bigger infinities good for?

Comment: The real numbers may themselves be of that cardinality!

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of misunderstanding in your question, I will try to go over them to explain them better.

> The power set of $\mathbb{R}$ is often described as being "bigger" or $\aleph_2$

$\aleph_0$ is how we denote the cardinality of $ℕ$, the countable infinity.

$\aleph_1$ is the minimal well orderable cardinal that is strictly bigger than $\aleph_0$ (I will later explain what "bigger" exactly means)

$\aleph_2$ is the minimal well orderable cardinal that is strictly bigger than $\aleph_1$.

We cannot, from the usual axioms of set theory, deduct completely the relation between the cardinality of the powerset of $ℝ$ to that of $\aleph_2$, the most we can say is that $|\mathcal{P}(ℝ)|≥\aleph_2$.

It is entirely possible that $|\mathcal{P}(ℝ)|>\aleph_2$, it is also possible that $|\mathcal{P}(ℝ)|=\aleph_2$. But you are correct by saying $|\mathcal P(ℝ)|>|ℝ|$, this relation is true for every set, not only $ℝ$.

By "$a$ is bigger than $b$" ($a>b$) we mean that there is injective from $a$ to $b$, but there is no bijection between them. (while equals means that there exists a bijection).

---

> One, what practical spaces of objects have a cardinality of $\aleph_2$?

This one is a bit tricky to answer, because there are 2 ways to look at it:

> > what kind of spaces have cardinality that is provable $\aleph_2$

Or

> > what kind of spaces have cardinality that can be $\aleph_2$

For the first variation, there are a lot of spaces (for example, we can show that there is a group of that cardinality), but most likely you won't find any example that is interesting by itself.

For the second variation: it is possible that $|ℝ|=\aleph_2$! It is also possible that the function space $ℝ^ℝ$, has cardinality $\aleph_2$.

---

> Are there any relevant theorems about mappings to and from sets that have a cardinality of $\aleph_2$?

Not really. Or rather, not anything special to $\aleph_2$. I kind find a lot of properties of such functions, but nothing of the form you would find in analysis most likely (for example: for any function from $\aleph_2$ to the naturals, there exists some natural $n$ whose pre-image is of cardinality $\aleph_2$)

---

> Further, does there exist a set with a cardinality of $\aleph_2$ that can be ordered, or is ordering intrinsically impossible on a set with such cardinality?

Any set of cardinality $\aleph_2$ can be well ordered. Like I said, by definition $\aleph_2$ is well orderable, so if $X$ is of cardinality $\aleph_2$, let $f:X→\aleph_2$ be a bijection, and define order on $X$ by $x<y⇔f(x)<f(y)$.

Although, saying anything about "intrinsically" is not really possible without more information about what your mean.

---

> In other words, why study larger infinities like $\aleph_2,$ what are these bigger infinities good for?

Like I said before, it is possible that $|ℝ|=\aleph_2$, and in fact, for each $\aleph_k$, it is possible that $|ℝ|>\aleph_k$. So maybe this is a good reason for you.

About why the powerset of $ℝ$ is interesting, tons of analysis relies on spaces of subsets of reals, e.g. topology, measure, and more.

Also, it is interesting research on it's own.

---

Note that apart from $\aleph_n$, there is also a definition of $\beth_n$: $\beth_0$ is exactly $\aleph_0$, $\beth_1$ is the cardinality of the powerset of $\beth_0$ (note that $\beth_1=|ℝ|$), $\beth_2$ is the cardinality of the powerset of $\beth_1$, so the powerset of the reals is of cardinality $\beth_2$.

Comment: @askquestions4: With the notation/terminology correction now taken care of, somewhat related to the OP's questioning is [Do any proofs/properties rely on the distinction between some uncountable size and a larger uncountable size, in order for the proof/property to hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3671589/13130). See also some papers by Frederick Otto Bagemihl (1920-2002), such as [*Decompositions of the plane into sets, and coverings of the plane with curves*](https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/100860) **(continued)**

Comment: AND [*The hypothesis* $2^{\aleph_0}\leq \aleph_n$ *and ambiguous points of planar functions*](https://eudml.org/doc/214008) and [*The present state of ambiguity theory*](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0304.04004). Of course, those MSE answers and Bagemihl's papers are probably well outside the scope of what is currently suitable for the OP to follow in detail, but they should nonetheless show that such applications do exist outside of pure set theory.