# Can a Taylor series approach two different values in the boundary of its domain of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Say that $f(z) = Σ a_n z^n$ has radius of convergence 1. Can there be a complex $u$ with $|u|= 1$ and two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ with $|x_n| < 1$, $|y_n| < 1$, $x_n → u$, and $y_n → u$, whose limits are finite: $-∞<\lim_{x_n→u} f(x_n)<∞$, and $-∞<\lim_{y_n→u} f(y_n)<∞$, yet $\lim_{x_n→u} f(x_n) \neq \lim_{y_n→u} f(y_n)$?

Comment: sure; for example, $f(z)=\exp \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ is bounded on the unit disc and of modulus $1$ on the unit circle except at $1$ where it is undefined and it is not hard to show that one can find $x_n \to 1, f(x_n) \to a$ for any $|a| \le 1$

Comment: @Conrad, your example answers my question as I wrote it. I mean to ask a slightly different question. I know of the Great Pickard theorem and your example is compatible with that theorem. Put your comment in the form of an answer and I will accept it. I will enhance the question in another post.

Comment: no problem - done;

Comment: For how deep your question can go, see the google search ["cluster set" + boundary + behavior + analytic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cluster+set%22+boundary+behavior+analytic&filter=0) and my answer to [Name for multi-valued analogue of a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114828/13130). Related is Andrés E. Caicedo's answer to [Behaviour of power series on their circle of convergence](https://mathoverflow.net/a/49411/15780) and my answer to [Power series which diverges precisely at the roots of unity, converges elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3014203/13130).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple example $f(z)=\exp \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ is bounded on the unit disc and of modulus $1$ on the unit circle except at $1$ where it is undefined and it is not hard to show that one can find $x_n \to 1, f(x_n) \to a$ for any $|a| \le 1$